# How to delete spaces In an 2D-Array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, string, trim

I have a text file. I am reading it then placing it into a 2D-Array. There are spaces. I need to get rid of those spaces. But I can't use `trim` properly. Here is my code:

```
while ((line = br.readLine() ) != null ){

    char[] row = line.toCharArray();
    line.trim();
    int counter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < row.length; i++) {
        maze[counter][i] = row[i];
        System.out.print(maze[i]);
        counter++;
    }
    System.out.printf("%n");
}
```

The output is as follows:

```
1                    1                    1                    0
0                    0                    1                    0
0                    0                    1                    0
0                    9                    1                    0
```

The elements in the text file I read has one space between each other. But I get too many spaces as output. I need to get this as

```
1110
0010
0010
0910
```

I think I should use `trim` method, but I could not figure it out.

Comment: `String#split` and `trim` might also help...Oh and `line.trim();` should be `line = line.trim();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`String#split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) with a regular expression of something like `\s+`, for example...

```
    String text = "1                    1                    1                    0";
    String elements[] = text.split("\\s+");
    for (String value : elements) {
        System.out.println("[" + value + "]");
    }
```

Which outputs

```
[1]
[1]
[1]
[0]
```

(The braces are there to demonstrate that no spaces remain)

In your example I might still be tempted to still us `line = line.trim();` to ensure that there are no leading or trailing space which might cause empty values to be included...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `(string).replace(" ", '\0')` to replace all spaces with blanks

For example:

```
    String line = "1 2  2 3 4 2 122 23  3  3 3 3";   //example
    line = line.replace(' ', '\0');  //'\0' is the key for blank (or nothing)
    System.out.println(line);
```

will produce

```
122342122233333
```

This will get rid of the spaces and only use the valid input (i.e. the numbers). It says row, but the only input will be the same characters.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You might want to run that through a code example and see what you actually get...

Comment: " " just consider one space and op has more than a space

Comment: It's not that there is anything "wrong", but you might want to check to see what that actually produces (hint, it won't produce an array of 4 elements)

Comment: @lacraig2 what was your outcome ?

Comment: `split(" ")` will split on EACH space, so when you have two spaces, it will create an empty result, as it tries to break between the two spaces...

Comment: @MadProgrammer I would've deleted, but I found an even better approach. It may be better than a split function since it leaves it as a single string.

Comment: That assumes that they want a `String` as the result, but I guess you can still use `charAt` or `toCharArray` to get the individual values...

Answer (score 0):

Quickest way for me would be to just use a nested loop to print each element of the array individually. E.g.

```
String [][] maze = new String [4][4];

     for (int i = 0; i < maze.length; i++) {

         maze[i][0] = "1";
         maze[i][1] = "0";
         maze[i][2] = "1";
         maze[i][3] = "0";

     }

     for (int k =0;k<maze.length;++k){

         for(int j=0;j<maze.length;++j)
         {
             System.out.print(maze[k][j]);
         }
         System.out.println();
     }
```